An animated film about assassinating Kim Jong-il
I watched it on TV one or two months ago. I didn't see its beginning nor its title. It's 3D animation. There is a team of American agents. It mentioned something about there are two or three types of people in the world, and North Korea's leader plotted to cause chaos and destruction by inviting every world leader to his peace conference and then nuke every city in the world. And a woman was captured by Kim Jong-il (maybe he was Kim Jong-un) and the main characters infiltrated the building, fought tigers and stopped the nuclear launch at the last second. Kim Jong-il died by falling onto a spike, and in the end, a cockroach exited from his mouth and escaped on a rocket.

were the two or three types of people  "dicks, pussies and assholes..." if so @layna is correct.

Sounds like Team America to me. Not sure if it fits 3D Animation, but both the dictator and the plot fit! 

A lot of people these days mistake stop motion animation for CG. I'm pretty certain you're correct.

and a new Gizmodo article just began talking about it.  http://gizmodo.com/movie-theaters-cant-even-show-team-america-now-because-1672828807

The theme song for Team America should have won a Grammy.
